# Journey Builder - When do sends occur?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

I have an automation audience that refills daily @ 5:05AM.

When I activate the Journey (say at 7:00pm) does that constitute the actual send time?  I also have 'Waits' within the journey.  Do those follow-up email sends occur at the same time (7:00pm).

Wanted to confirm that the new subscribers getting injected at 5:05am aren't receiving an email at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first email is also the first activity, then the time of the first contact entry is the time of send. So if the journey entry is triggered by an automation at 05:05am this will be the time of the first send.

> The audience created from this data extension enters the journey according to the automation's schedule. Contacts do not enter the journey upon journey activation.
> (Source: [Create an Automation Studio Audience](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/journey_builder_audiences/create_an_automation_studio_audience/))

Wait activities are always the exact time between the previous and the next activity so if a send occurs at 5:05am and your wait is set to 1 day the next send will occur at 5:05am the following day.

> - Use the Duration option to choose how long the wait period lasts when it is not necessary to release contacts at a specific time of day.
> - Use the Duration + Time option to set the wait period and specify the day and time contacts proceed. When an activity like Send Email or Send SMS follows the Wait activity, this setting prevents messages from being sent at an inconvenient time of day.
>   (Source: [Use the Wait Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/using_the_wait_activity/))

**Related documentation:**

- [Create an Automation Studio Audience](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/journey_builder_audiences/create_an_automation_studio_audience/)
- [Use the Wait Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/using_the_wait_activity/)